# Integral how to choose the good substitution?

Tags: integration

I have a problem with this integral. I don't know what kind of substitution to use.

$$\int t\sqrt{1+9t^4}dt$$

Comment: Use the substitution $3t^2=x$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\int t\sqrt{1+9t^4}\space\text{d}t=$$

---

Substitute $u=t^2$ and $\text{d}u=2t\space\text{d}t$:

---

$$\frac{1}{2}\int\sqrt{1+9u^2}\space\text{d}u=$$

---

Substitute $u=\frac{\tan(s)}{3}$ and $\text{d}u=\frac{\sec^2(s)}{3}\space\text{d}s$.

Then $\sqrt{1+9u^2}=\sqrt{1+\tan^2(s)}=\sec(s)$ and $s=\arctan\left(3u\right)$:

---

$$\frac{1}{6}\int\sec^3(s)\space\text{d}s=$$
$$\frac{\tan(s)\sec(s)}{12}+\frac{1}{12}\int\sec(s)\space\text{d}s=$$
$$\frac{\tan(s)\sec(s)}{12}+\frac{\ln\left|\tan(s)+\sec(s)\right|}{12}+\text{C}=$$
$$\frac{\tan(s)\sec(s)+\ln\left|\tan(s)+\sec(s)\right|}{12}+\text{C}=$$
$$\frac{\tan\left(\arctan\left(3u\right)\right)\sec\left(\arctan\left(3u\right)\right)+\ln\left|\tan\left(\arctan\left(3u\right)\right)+\sec\left(\arctan\left(3u\right)\right)\right|}{12}+\text{C}=$$
$$\frac{3u\sqrt{1+9u^2}+\sinh^{-1}(3u)}{12}+\text{C}=$$
$$\frac{3t^2\sqrt{1+9t^4}+\sinh^{-1}(3t^2)}{12}+\text{C}$$

Comment: For your second substitution isn't that supposed to be  $du=\frac{sec^{2}(t}{3}dt$

Answer (score 2):

$$
\Big( t\,dt\Big)
$$
What you see above suggests at least considering $u=t^2$ so that $du=2t\,dt$, and then what you see above is $\frac 1 2 \, du$.

Since you have $9t^4 = (3t^2)^2$, using $u=3t^2$ works; then $du = 6t\,dt$ and $\frac 1 6 \, du = t\,dt$.

And then you have $9t^4 = (3t^2)^2 = u^2$, so $\displaystyle\int \sqrt{1+9t^4}\ t\, dt = \frac 1 6 \int\sqrt{1+u^2}\  du$.

Comment: $\int t \sqrt {1 + 9 t^4} dt = \frac {1} {6} \int \sqrt {1 + u^2} du$ so correct it please. Also I don't see how $\int \sqrt {1 + u^2} du$ is simpler.

Comment: Once you've got $\displaystyle\int\sqrt{1+u^2}\,du$ you can use a trigonometric substitution.  $u=\tan\theta$ reduces the integral to $\displaystyle \int \sec^3\theta\,d\theta$.  That may be somewhat challenging by itself if never seen before, but it is widely known. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: I edited your post. Also, you keep making the integral more and more difficult. There must be an insight to actually make it easier to handle. To a beginner like myself, clever manipulations are better than heavy technical manipulations. (Please don't take this as a criticism. I may have a lot to learn from you!)

Comment: The first substitution reduces it to something familiar.

Answer (score 1):

$$\int t \sqrt{1-9t^4} \, dt $$
$$=\frac{1}{6}\int 6t \sqrt{1-9t^4} \, dt $$
$$=\frac{1}{6}\int \sqrt{1-9t^4} \, d(3t^2) $$
$$=\frac{1}{6}\int \sqrt{1-(3t^2)^2} \, d(3t^2) $$

Now apply standard formula.

Comment: Hi there, use substitution $3t^2=sin(x)$ then $tdt=1/6cos(x)dx$

Comment: @M.R.Yegan If you want to write an answer, please do so. Do not write it in my post's comment section.

Comment: @Aniket Why not? Maybe he wants to communicate with you over your solution.

Comment: What does $d(3t^2)$ mean and how would we integrate with respect to $3t^2$?

Comment: @AhmedS.Attaalla You just need the substitution $u=3t^2$.In advanced stages, you don't write the $u$ anymore, you directly write it as $d(3t^2)$.

Answer (score -1):

$3t^2 = \sin x$, $t\,dt=\frac{1}{6} \cos x \,dx$. So, we have,

$$\int \cos x (1/6) \cos x \, dx =\int \frac{1}{12}(1+\cos2x) \, x 
= \frac {1} {12} (x + \sin x \cos x)+c=\frac{1}{12}\left(\arcsin(3t^2)+3t^2\sqrt{1-9t^4}\right)+c.$$

Comment: Dear Nima  I am the author of the textbook calculus1 which  introduced in the site "www.azadimath.com" If you are in Iran you can refer to this book for a progressive discussion in integrals.

Comment: Wow, agha, shoma Irooni hastin? I'll check it out!

Comment: This is simply wrong. Note that there is a plus sign inside the square root, and not a minus sign.